# Integration of Rcpp in c++ with bcc compiler

Tags: c++, rcpp, rinside

I'm looking for a library in c++ which I compile with the Borland compiler bcc32.
Before I tried to take the benefits of RInside but unfortunately it's only working with gcc-compiler and can't be used in my programming environment, which is Embarcadero.

1. Is it possible to use Rcpp with a bcc32 compiler?
2. Are there compatible libraries on the market doing statistical calculations in c++?

I hope you can help me. Thanks.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_Algorithms_Group

Answer (score 1):

Part 1: no.  From the [Rcpp FAQ](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-FAQ.pdf):

> 1.3.  What compiler can I use. On almost all platforms, the GNU
>   Compiler Collection (or gcc, which is also the name of its
>   C language compiler) has to be used along with the corresponding
>   g++ compiler for the
>   C++ language.  ...
>   The
>   clang
>   and
>   clang++
>   compilers from the LLVM project can
>   also be used ...
>   The Intel
>   icc
>   family has also been used successfully as its output
>   files can also be combined with those from
>   gcc
>   .

If it's not on that list, it's not supported.

Part 2: off topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks, Ben, and to add:  this isn't because we're meanies.  We use and support all the tool-chains supported by R.  Which does not include `bcc32`.  So there.